# github-jenkins webhook issue

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

i am trying to integrate github with jenkins. while doing this i added github webhook with below jenkins address

http://xxx.xxx.1.103:8080/github-webhook/

however on adding it in github, i  get below message(as shown in screenshot-red warning)
"Last delivery was not successful, could not connect to server"

When i do any commit/push jenkins build is not getting triggered. Please refer to attached screenshots.

Is there any settings i am missing here?

**I tried couple of things here however could not succeed:**
1.have opened my ports 8080 on internet and tried to do the push event.
2.copied "override hook url" specified in jenkins
3.instead of webhook i tried to add it as service too, but it didnot work[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can see you actually use 192.168.1.103

... It cannot be reached by GitHub since private IPs are not rooted in the internet.

You have to use an external IP you can reach from the Internet. If you are connected to the internet using a gateway/router than you will have to setup some kind of forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

The issue over here is that your GitHub cannot find the IP address that you have set.
To find your IP address you can use ngrok and then find your IP on the port where your jenkins is running example:

ngrok http 8080

To know how ngrok works refer :
https://ngrok.com/product

You will then get your IP address on port 8080, which will look something like https://228b9f82.ngrok.io/github-webhook/ . Write this as your Payload URL. 
At this point when you save it, it will send a post request to ngrok server, got redirected to localhost and you will see a green tick.

Also for complete integration process(Setting up) of jenkins github webhook refer this :
https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline